# Can not find a good pie chart jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a big problem visualizing the following :

I have 4 categories : sureness(with some positive and negative values) 
kindness(with some positive and negative values)
happiness(with some positive and negative values) 
 calmness(with some positive and negative values)

I want to show them in pie chart with 4 labels kindness, happiness and calmness and sureness
with the contribution of negative and positive values on a layer above each

I used graphel pie chart but it did not give me the multilayer piechart.

does anyone know any jquery plugin that can be fit with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using Google Charts in the past: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart

I think it would do what you need. No need to use jQuery specifically.